# Access my projects details in Microsoft Project server 2013 errors?

Tags: ms-project, project-server

I have created one PWA(Project Web App) site in MS Project server 2013

I created projects on it it was working fine,

but after some time when I wanted to access my projects details page

it give a loop error:

```
An error occurred while opening your project. Give us a few minutes and try again. If this happens again, contact your administrator.
```

can anyone tell what cause the error in MS Project Server 2013 Web App

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked permissions in Groups & Categories?  It could be as simple as needing to add "Open Project," "View Project Site" "View Project Schedule in Project Web App" and "View Project Summary in Project Center" (in Categories).

I have had weird permissions issues cause such loops.  It would be a good place to start if you haven't already investigated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue most like occurs as a result of values being changed for custom field lookup tables.  If you know what lookup tables have been modified, consider updating the tables and try again.

If you have access to the ULS logs, the details may provide you with a better insight to the actual data error.